# Run untrusted application safely through sandbox-exec command

Tags: security, bash, malware, anti-virus, sandbox

I'm trying to run a potentially untrusted application without the following permissions, through the `sandbox-exec` command:

1. file write (to avoid corruption/injection of files)
2. network (to avoid communicate outside of my network)
3. process creation (to avoid forks)
4. access to system data (to avoid system corruption)

Let's suppose I need to run my application `MyApp`.
I know it's possible to create a profile `myprofile.sb` such as the following one, but I'm not sure everything is included.

```
(version 1)
(allow default)
# bullet point #1
(deny file-write*)
(deny file-write-data)
# bullet point #2
(deny network*)
# bullet point #3
(deny process-fork)
(deny job-creation)
(deny process-exec)
# bullet point #4
(deny sysctl-write)
# logging every action possible
(trace "/tmp/myapp_output.sb")
(debug all)
```

At this point, I run the following command to run `MyApp` safely:

```
sandbox-exec -f ./myprofile.sb MyApp
```

If I run sample commands (e.g. `ping google.it` or `touch /tmp/file.txt`), the commands are executed correctly. Why? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but maybe someone finds the answer useful.

The *trace* operation generates rules in the given output file.

> These rules are for operations that **would have been denied**.
>   (source: [Apple Sandbox Guide](https://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Apple-Sandbox-Guide-v1.0.pdf))

Which means: the operations are not denied by the deny rules if the *trace* operator is in the profile file.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you update it?

Comment: Works from here. Unfortunately I can't find another copy of the document on the web, so this is the only link I can provide.